# How to pause a pre-implemented Runnable class in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, jung2

I have got the following `animator` class that implements Runnable (mentioned in [JUNG documentation](http://jung.sourceforge.net/site/apidocs/edu/uci/ics/jung/visualization/util/Animator.html)).

How can tell the `thread` , if some condition was true `pause` for some time and then `start` running?

```
    switch (args[0]) 
    {
        case "agent":
            int size=nodeAttributes.size();
            int i;
            for(i=0;i<size;i++)
            {
                if(args[1].equals(nodeAttributes.get(i).nodeName))
                {
                    VertexCollider vtxCol = new VertexCollider(layout, panel,args[1], args[2] , args[1] , nodeAttributes.get(i));
                    vtxCol.setMaximumIterations(1000);
                    vtxCol.setDesiredPrecision(1);
                    vtxCol.initialize();
                    Animator  animator = new Animator(vtxCol);

                    animator.start();
                    if(nodeAttributes.get(i).isMoving)
                    {
                        animator.stop();
                        animator.wait(10000);
                        System.out.println("stopped");
                    }
                    nodeAttributes.get(i).isMoving = true;
                    break;  
                }
            }
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pause the the `animator` you must first move the `animator` object and `vtxCol` object Initialization to another Thread.Because even if the `Thread.sleep()` function or `wait()` function are about to work for your purpose they will stop the function Initializing the `animator` too which may not fit your needs.

After moving the `animator` object creation to another separate Thread you must consider creating some `LinkedList` , `Array` or some kind of `Collection` for holding your movement data in order to Initialize the `vtxCol` and `animator` object by them , And pass the data to the thread. Then in the `Thread.sleep()` function can answer your need in that separate thread created.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation you referenced, an `Animator` can be paused for a certain amount of time between iteration loops.

```
animator.setSleepTime(10000);
```

And then you could set the sleep time to a much shorter interval when your pause condition ended.

However, it seems like you want your Animator to stop entirely when the pause condition is true. In that case, I recommend you `stop()` the animator at that time (as your code is doing), and then `start()` it again when the pause condition ends. It appears you can call the stop and start methods repeatedly.

Comment: The problem is if I `stop` the animator  or set the `sleep time` to a long duration ,The program does not return to the function for checking the condition value (And no other function runs after executing this function) and `starting` or changing the `sleep time to shorter interval` Where should I recheck it again?

Comment: Sorry man, I can't solve your design problem using this small amount of information. If you want your animator to wait a while, you can tell it to sleep between loops. If you want to stop and start your animator, you'll have to figure out how to come back and start it.

Comment: I have got the complete implementation in the another question if you want to take a look [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28003792/how-to-pause-jung-animator-given-an-iterativeprocess-by-using-thread-sleep?rq=1] .

Answer (score 0):

Place wherever you want the program to sleep: (inside an if statement?)

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(1);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

this will tell the thread to sleep however many milliseconds you want it to.

in do-while:

```
do{

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}while(something() == true);
```

this will keep on checking the value, until it is false.

Comment: I don't want to make the `program` sleep. I just want the `animator` class that implements `runnable` to sleep for some time and then execute.

Comment: Yes the documentation says it is a independent `thread` , and it's also a `protected thread`.

Comment: @AliNfr, then calling `Thread.sleep(milliseconds)` should not hang the entire program, it should only sleep the thread that the animator is on.

Comment: Your solution just has the same problem that I mentioned to @gknicker.

Comment: put this in a do-while loop.

Comment: What do you mean? The `Thread.sleep(milliseconds) ` that you just mentioned can not be used inside the animator class , so it hangs the entire program.

Comment: Because there are other instances of animator and other classes running and I don't want them to be stopped.

Comment: @AliNfr, the Thread.sleep() only hangs the current thread, (which is this animator thread) and the others keep on going.

Comment: The `current thread` is the thread that calls the `animator` class , then the `animator` class itself creates another thread and continues executing.

Comment: Therefore, the inner thread is hung, while the one that calls the class is not.

Comment: Do you mean calling the `Thread.sleep()` inside the animator class? if not the `Thread.sleep()` function sleeps `the calling class` that is not appropriate.

Comment: Oh, you didn't write the animator class? Sorry I thought you meant to write the code INSIDE the animator class. XD oops